# Java code not working (Reached end of file while parsing)

Tags: java

So I was making something funny for my teacher and I can't seem to find the problem. THe only error is that it says it reached the end of the file while parsing

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Get Pershing to work");
        System.out.println("Is Pershing working? (Y/N)");
        Scanner isWork = new Scanner(System.in);
        String workInput = isWork.nextLine();
        if (isWork.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            System.out.println("Pat him on  the head and say good job");
        }
        if (isWork.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.out.println("Smack him or send him to the office");

        }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` has no `equalsIgnoreCase` method . Did you mean `workInput.equalsIgnoreCase` ?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, change these lines:

```
isWork.equalsIgnoreCase("y")
isWork.equalsIgnoreCase("n")
```

to

```
workInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")
workInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n")
```

For me your code did not compile.